# Ubuntu - после обновления kernel при загрузке просто черный экран

Tags: linux, ubuntu

После обновления kernel на 4.13 при загрузке Ubuntu просто черный экран.
При запуске системы на старом ядре(4.10) все работает.

Comment: Подождите 14.4 (пока, наверное, какая-то проблема с драйверами)

Comment: Как обновляли? - с офф реп, ppa, самосборное? какая бубунта? На сколько древнее/новое железо?